# Tailwind right property not working when position is set to sticky

Tags: tailwind-css

I am trying to align an item to the right of the screen and make it sticky.
But as you can see in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-clarke-bqh1l?file=/index.html) it's not working.
The right property is not applied.
What should i do?

Answer (score 3):

This will also be working

```
<div class="sticky top-0 right-10 w-full flex justify-end">
  <div class="bg-blue-400 w-40">hossein</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

[Here is the solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-bose-x4jlg?file=/index.html), in this case we add a wrapper (with full width) and set right margin of given element to `auto`. Also this is not Tailwind's fault since all classes are present on element (which means it works). In case you want element to float use this instead `<div class="sticky top-0 float-right bg-blue-400 w-40">hossein</div>`.